# Send database notification in Flutter

Tags: python, sql-server, flutter

I am using mssql as database in the application I am working in Flutter. I want the user to be notified when there is any change in the database. I made the database connection by writing flask api in Python. What way would you suggest I follow?

Comment: try to use onesignal.com. it's free to use and easy.

Comment: It redirects me to firebase. But my database is Microsoft SQL.